# How to seed data in codeigniter

Tags: php

How to seed data in CodeIgniter after migrating?
I want to seed some pre-define users after the migration of table user once the migration completed.

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Users extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $dbprefix = $this->db->dbprefix;
        $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
                'id' => array(
                        'type' => 'INT',
                        'constraint' =>11,
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'auto_increment' => TRUE
                ),
                'first_name' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => 50
                ),
                'last_name' => array(
                        'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                        'constraint' => 50,
                )
             ));
       $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('users');
      }

    public function down()
    {
            $this->dbforge->drop_table('users');
    }
 }
```

Comment: For Codeignitor 4, this should help: https://bcit-ci.github.io/CodeIgniter4/database/seeds.html

Answer (score 4):

*I know this post is pretty old, but its comes up as the first result in google when searching for 'code igniter seeding in migration'. So thought I'd offer my solution.*

You can quite easily perform simple `$this->db->query($sql)` methods within the up and down methods within the migration.

For my particular case I was seeding some static hash data, so put the values in a property of the migration and read from it in a loop, each time creating the SQL Insert query from my seed array.

Here is a redacted, reduced example of my seed migration file:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Seed_hash_table extends CI_Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        foreach ($this->seedData as $seed ) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO hash_table VALUES '.$seed;
            $this->db->query($sql);
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        foreach ($this->seedData as $seed) {
            $hash = substr($seed, 2, 32);
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM hash_table WHERE hash = \''.$hash.'\'';
            $this->db->query($sql);
        }
    }

    private $seedData = array(
        '("2a96e53846b6232662fff87128061bbd", "Value A",)',
        '("7c78ebb4c223c96fa9c5e6s3f73cc28e", "Value B",)',
        '("ad2cb75a968ca5ef3255d924076e902f", "Value C",)',
    );
}
```

*Note: The example above has had all error checking removed to stay small for posting purposes.*

This of course relies on your data schema being in place *(in the previous migration)*, and all values in your `$seedData` property being the latter/right hand side of your INSERT query, with all your columns specified.

But you get the idea. =)

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that: it completely bypasses all of your model's business logic and it also isn't suitable for times when you might want to run your migrations in production

Comment: I could use it.