# How to use database seeds to create user in codeigniter-3 version?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have setup the project in CodeIgniter-3 version. I want to do migrations and seeding in it. I successfully implemented the migration of tables, now I want to perform seeding operation in it but I don't know how I can do it in codeigniter-3 version. Is there way to perform seeding operations so that I can insert username and password in my user table. I have setup all this in my local system. Any help will be appreciated. If you need any info please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you're after Inserting data into the database which can be found here - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data

Comment: And this has been asked elsewhere ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934009/how-to-seed-data-in-codeigniter

Comment: @Antony thanks for the reply. I have checked the link already you have referred me but its not the solution of my problem. I want to seed data as it is implemented in CodeIgniter 4

Comment: Hi, could you please update your question because there is no mention of CodeIgniter 4 anywhere, even if you talk about migration.